# Is there a way to use tinsel in a package?

Tags: r

Having come from python and now using R I'm trying to bring across some decorator patterns to include in an R package I'm writing.

I have found the [tinsel R package](https://github.com/nteetor/tinsel) which looks to be the closest thing I can find to the python decorator syntax. However, it requires that the source files get loaded in through `source_decorates`. The problem I have is that if I want to use the decoration in a package I don't want to have to use `source` to get the package's files included.

I guess outside of using tinsel there are ways to implement decoration such as passing the declaration of the function through the decorator before assigning it to the name.

The following I am against because it requires the matching of the brackets at the end so isn't so simple to implment and is a lot more complicated to autogenerate decoration of groups of functions.

```
decorated_function <- decorator(function(...){})
```

I did see the following which I guess might be the best option

```
`%decorate%` <- function(decorator, .f){
    decorator(.f)
}
decorated_function <- decorator %decorate% function(...){}
```

To be clear the question is on if I can use tinsel inside a package

Comment: I don't see how *"matching of the brackets at the end"* is so onerous. If your second option of using `%decorate%` is palatable, then what's your question? R doesn't have pythons `@my_decorator` notation, so either you wrap it or you `%decorate%` it (as you've suggested.

Comment: Sorry the exta options might have made it less clear. The question is how to use the tinsel package inside a package

Comment: With regards to the onerous nature of brackets is that it can't be manipulated with a sed command. FSA vs context free grammar

Comment: I have so rarely needed to use `sed` on an R package, I can't imagine what you're doing ... though given that, I understand your aversion to wrapping a function the "normal R" way. As for using `tinsel` in a package, I know of no way to do it. I think your use of `%decorate%` is the best you're going to do, at which point you don't need `tinsel` as the functions are straight-forward. I understand your question, though. Based on the fact that it has not been updated in 5 years from its "initial release", are you sure you want to rely on it?

Comment: Good point. Thank you for your help

Comment: Working with the last option of %decorator% i am wondering if doc-strings are still working. Does anyone has experience with this?

Comment: I checked also for the use of docstrings. It worked out to be doumented with devtools::document(). However, the built-in sugar of RSTudio to create a Roxygen Skeleton doesn't work as it expects a function.